# Creating Model in Flutter

Tags: c#, flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:kool_selling/models/kool_m_base_models.dart';

class AddressModel extends AddressCustom {
  AddressModel(
      {required String addressNumber,
      required String addressText,
      required CountryCustom countryObj,
      required ProvinceCustom provinceObj,
      required DistrictCustom districtObj,
      required WardCustom wardObj})
      : super(
            addressNumber: addressNumber,
            addressText: addressText,
            countryObj: countryObj,
            provinceObj: provinceObj,
            districtObj: districtObj,
            wardObj: wardObj);
}
```

I want to create some model in Flutter that is base on some model from C# to do fromJson and toJson API calls but I don't know if the model I made was correct please help me [image: C# Models]

[image: This is what I had created, don't know if it is correct or if there some missing part to it]

Comment: could you please instead of screen shot provide your code?

Comment: Which part of the code do you need?

Comment: your addressModel.

Comment: please add these CountryCustom, ProvinceCustom,DistrictCustom, WardCustom classes too. or just say what are they made of.

Answer (score 0):

use this [converter](https://ashamp.github.io/jsonToDartModel/) to create model

[image]

it will convert `null-safe` model which will be useful to code `faster` and `scalable`.